# CodeIgniter with a PostgreSQL multiple schemas issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql, connection

I am developing an agent-port application in CodeIgniter with PostgreSQL by using mutiple schemas from a single database. The setup I have designed is working fine.

So the problem I am facing right now is when after some interval it starts showing the following errors on different pages, like:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\mangonet\application\modules\settings\models\adminmodel.php
> on line 30
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\mangonet\application\modules\users\models\adminmodel.php
> on line 56
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\mangonet\application\modules\users\models\adminmodel.php
> on line 86

**Let me give one example**

I try to find out a particular problem only if it always remains there. But when I refresh my page or remove that row() from the function

```
function get_item_by_id($table, $id)
{
    return $this->db->get_where($table, array('id' => $id))->row();
}
```

it returns a black result and when I add it back, the problem gone, and it starts working fine.
I know the above fatal errors you can see above solutions are available. But my problem is a bit complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with database connections going away.  I would recommend looking at debugging this on the application side.  In particular I would start logging the following:

1. Database connection status on all problematic calls.  In other words check and see if the database connection has closed or failed.
2. If the database connection has not failed, then the next thing to check is what the search path is.  You can execute the following query to test it:

   ```
   SHOW search_path;
   ```

It is possible that if this is related to multiple schemas, something is messing with that.